# Flag that indicates tweet has adult content

Tags: c#, twitter

Does Twitter mark either its users, or their tweets, with some sort of flag which indicates that they may contain sensitive/adult content? My intent is to filter these tweets on a set of rules.

I've already implemented a primitive redacting API, but I want to know if Twitter's already provided hooks for me to tinker with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `possibly_sensitive` property for that.

Example: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid